# SharePoint Designer Define workflow lookup question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, lookup-column, sharepoint-designer-workflow, workflow-lookup

SharePoint Designer 2013 lookup workflow values there are 4 columns and I'm not sure what they mean and whenever I try it doesn't work but once they are just 2 columns they work perfectly. Wondering what the values will be in the top 2 columns and the last two. Usually  I use the same for both.
How it work

[image]

Comment: Just like the UI shows, the two column in the button asks user to provide information for SharePoint Designer to find the correct item. I will explain a bit more in the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This window basically is asking for more information to get filed value from a SharePoint List.

`Data source`: The list/library you are trying to access and get information.

`Field from source`: The column you try to access.

`Return filed as`: Just like it says, you can choose the type (date, string, integer) of the value you get from the column in data source. For example, you are trying to get a single text column and need to use the string value in it, then you can choose the type to be string in this option to make sure you get a string from the column.

And for most of the cases there are multiple items in a list, we need to find the items we want with some criteria. And the `Find the List Item` part helps us to do this.

`Field`: You choose a column here and set it as the identifier for you to get the correct items. Let's say we are trying to get all the items has the "Number" column equals 10, then we will need to choose Number column in this field. It is the filed holding value we are comparing with the criteria or standard we need.

`Value`: Following the explanation above, here we are setting the value of the standard. With the example I made, we will fill in 10 here. And you can see the function button, click on it will enable you to construct complex equation, like comparing the filed value with values in another list.